# Is there way to get the corresponding item using next and next all expression of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have module regarding getting the right corresponding parent item and parent child, so to get the each item and the child I use the next and nextAll expression of jquery. I will share to you guys my output right now, and the output I want to be.

**This is my output right now (Which this output is wrong)**

[image: Output wrong]

**The output should be look like this**
[image: output wanted]

My output in my web app. **as you can see on my highlighted items there is no children however in my console log when I submit the button the highlighted item repeat the output on the first item ordered**

To append the item to that list I use this code.

```
    $("tr#productClicked").click(function () {

      var menu_name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_name").text();
      var menu_price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_price").text();
      var chain_id =  $(this).closest("tr").find(".chain_id").text();
      var menu_image = $(this).closest("tr").find(".menu_image").attr('src');


      swal({
      title: "Are you sure to add " + menu_name + " ?",
      text: "Once you will add it will automatically send to the cart",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((willInsert) => {

      if (willInsert) {
        swal("Successfully Added to your form.", {
          icon: "success",
        });



       if(chain_id == 0) {

           $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
              append("<tr class='condimentParent' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td class='total'>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithOutCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");

       }
       else
       {
          $.ajax({
            url:'/get_noun_group_combination',
            type:'get',
            data:{chain_id:chain_id},
            success:function(response){

               var noun_chaining = response[0].noun_chaining;

               $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
              append("<tr class='condimentParent' style='background-color:'black !important',color:'white !important' '><td></td><td>"+menu_name+"</td><td class='total'>"+menu_price+"</td><td><button class='removeorderWithCondi btn btn-danger form-control'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td></tr>");

               $.each(noun_chaining, function (index, el) {

                var stringify_noun_chaining = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));

                // console.log(stringify['menu_cat_image']);
                var Qty = stringify_noun_chaining['Qty'];
                var Condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['Condiments'];
                var Price = stringify_noun_chaining['Price'];
                var allow_to_open_condiments = stringify_noun_chaining['allow_to_open_condiments'];

                var condiments_section_id = stringify_noun_chaining['condiments_section_id'];


                $("tbody#tbody_noun_chaining_order").
                append("<tr class='editCondiments'>\
                <td class='condiments_order_quantity'>"+Qty+"</td>\
                <td>*"+Condiments+"</td><td class='total'>"+Price+"</td>\
                <td class='allow_to_open_condiments_conditional' style='display:none;'>"+allow_to_open_condiments+"</td>\
                <td class='condi_section_id' style='display:none;'>"+condiments_section_id+"</td>\
                </tr>");


              })

            },
            error:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
       }

    }
  });
```

[image: Web app]

**This is my add to cart button when inserting the item to the database.**

```
    $('button#add_to_cart').on('click',function () {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

      $parent = $(this).closest("tr.condimentParent");


      var menu= $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent');

          menu.next('.condimentParent').add(menu).each(function(){


            if(menu.length > 0 ) {

              var $tds_menu = $(this).find("td");

                    Qty_menu = $tds_menu.eq(0).text(),
                    Item_menu = $tds_menu.eq(1).text(),
                    Price_menu = $tds_menu.eq(2).text();

                    console.log(Item_menu);



                var condiments= $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments');

                  condiments.nextAll('.editCondiments').add(condiments).each(function(){

                    var $tds_condiments = $(this).find("td");
                    Qty_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(0).text(),
                    Item_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(1).text(),
                    Price_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(2).text();

                    console.log(Item_condiments);


                });
            }




      });

});
```

Comment: Need the HTML as well and can you please post the entirety of your code as a [mcve]? If the HTML is dynamically generated then post the HTML as it is after it is generated and label it as such.

Comment: sure @zer00ne i will show you my appended ordered to the list.

Comment: @zer00ne post updated

Comment: So there's no items within BIG CRUNCH Box?

Comment: yes, @zer00ne the item have a child is $5.00 Extra Crispy 2 Piece Box

Comment: I think the problem, the child is on the each of parent item

Comment: `...condiments.nextAll('.editCondiments').add(condiments).each(function() {` `condiments` is a `tr` so `.nextAll()` will get every `tr` that follows it.

Comment: what do you mean zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192016/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-devge).

Comment: why someone give me downvote for this?

Answer (score 0):

To solved my problem i use multiple add

```
    $('button#add_to_cart').on('click',function () {

    var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();

      $parent = $(this).closest("tr.condimentParent");

      var condiments= $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.editCondiments');
      var menu= $('#noun_chaining_order').find('tr.condimentParent');

          menu.next('.condimentParent').add(menu).add(condiments).each(function(){

              var $tds_menu = $(this).find("td");

              Qty_menu = $tds_menu.eq(0).text(),
              Item_menu = $tds_menu.eq(1).text(),
              Price_menu = $tds_menu.eq(2).text();

              console.log(Item_menu);



              //   condiments.nextAll('.editCondiments').add(condiments).each(function(){

              //     var $tds_condiments = $(this).find("td");
              //     Qty_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(0).text(),
              //     Item_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(1).text(),
              //     Price_condiments = $tds_condiments.eq(2).text();

              //     console.log(Item_condiments);


              // });

          });



});
```